# using xelatex and keeping the other fonts

Tags: xetex, fontspec, unicode, font-encodings, tipa

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, scheme = plain, twoside]{ctexart}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath,enumerate,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % uses graphicx
\graphicspath{{./figs/}}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[top=1.68cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1.68cm]{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{18pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{blue}}
%% \columnbreak
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{style = nextline}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lxfonts}
%%% \usepackage{fontspec}
%%% \setmainfont{Doulos SIL}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{totpages}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{Vocabulary for iG \& A Level Mathematics}
\fancyhead[R]{Page~\thepage\ of~\pageref{TotPages}}
\fancyfoot[LO]   {{\heiti非淡泊无以明志，非宁静无以致远。}}
\fancyfoot[RE]   {{\heiti书山有路勤为径，学海无涯苦作舟。}}
%%% \fancyfoot[LO]   {{非淡泊无以明志，非宁静无以致远。}}
%%% \fancyfoot[RE]   {{书山有路勤为径，学海无涯苦作舟。}}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{{XXXXXXXXX}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarksopen  = false,
    pdfstartview   = {FitV},         % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdfpagelayout  = TwoPageRight    % UseOutlines, %UseNone-disable bookmark panel
}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pdfsuppressptexinfo = -1 %% noinfo
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\titlerule[1.8pt]}[{\titlerule[1.8pt]}]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\title{Vocabulary for iG \& A Level Mathematics}
\date{\today}
\author{}
\onehalfspacing
%% \doublespacing
\pagestyle{fancy}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{multicols}{2}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{A -- Alpha}
\begin{description}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\item[Acceleration /əkˌseləˈreɪʃ(ə)n/]
    The rate of change of velocity over time.
\item[Adjacent /əˈdʒeɪ.sənt/]
    Of a right-angled triangle,
    it's the side between the angle under consideration and the right angle.
%   \begin{center}
%   \includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}
%   \end{center}
\item[Algebraic fraction]
    A fraction that has an algebraic expression in the numerator and/or denominator.
\item[Allied /'ælaɪd/ angles]
    The pair of angles in a C-- or U--shape formed when a straight line crosses two parallel lines.
    These angles always add up to $180^\circ$.
\item[AND rule (for dependent events)]
    The probability of both $A$ and $B$ happening 
    is equal to the probability of $A$ happening 
    multiplied by the probability of $B$ happening given that $A$ has happened.
\item[AND rule (for independent events)]
    The probability of both $A$ and $B$ happening is 
    equal to the probability of $A$ happening 
    multiplied by the probability of $B$ happening.
%   \begin{center}
%   \includegraphics[scale=1]{and_rule.pdf}
%   \end{center}
\item[Angle bisector /baɪˈsektə/]
    The line that cuts an angle into two equal smaller angles.
\item[Angle of depression/elevation]
    The angle between a horizontal line and 
    the line of sight of an observer 
    at the same level looking down or up, respectively.
%   \begin{center}
%   \includegraphics[scale=0.82]{elevation_depression.pdf}
%   \end{center}
\item[Arc /ˈɑːk/]
    A part of the circumference of a circle.
\item[Arithmetic /əˈrɪθ.mə.tɪk/ (or linear) sequence]
    A sequence where the terms increase or decrease by the same amount each time 
    (the common difference $d$).
    \[
        u_n = a + (n-1)d,
    \]
    where $a$ is the first term and $u_n$ is the $n$\textsuperscript{th} term.
\item[Asymptote /ˈæs.ɪm.təʊt/]
    A straight line to show the values where the graph of a function is undefined.
\item[Average]
    A way of representing a set of data with a central or typical value of the set.
    The three common averages used are the mode, median and mean.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{description}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{multicols}
\end{document}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Main purpose is to enable unicode for the phonetics in the code. So did some seacher and saw that I have to use xelatex to compile it.

However, then is there a way to keep the fonts (not phonetics) using

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lxfonts}
```

as well as the `\heiti` in my fancy footer? They dont seem to be working with xelatex?

In short, I want the out put to be exaclty as in the picture below WITH the correctly displayed IPA. Is that possible?
[image]

At the moment, if I want to display the IPA, the rest of the document just looks so plain....
[image]

Comment: no, if you want to use xelatex you should remove fontenc and the font package. but you can use unicode input also with pdflatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Really???? I read a lot of IPA posts and none of them mentioned that I could typeset /əkˌseləˈreɪʃ(ə)n/ with unicode....it's pretty much either tipa package or unicode with xelatex.......

Comment: @UlrikeFischer What I meant was, yes I tried just to run it with pdflatex, but failed to see /əkˌseləˈreɪʃ(ə)n/ in the end....just looks like the font problem...

Comment: you only need to declare the character. It is a bit work: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0259}{\textreve}
\begin{document}
\textipa{ə}
\end{document}`